# How to make a text file not accessable?

Tags: php, html

i have recently added a IP-Logger to my site just to mess around with it.
The ips are being saved in a file called "ips.txt".
However, im able to access that file by typing in "domain.com/ips.txt".
Is there a way to prevent people having access to that site?

I also have another question,
whenever i log the time the person visited the website, it's different then when he actually visited it. I currently have this code 
`$logdetails=date("d-m-Y H:i:s")`. Lets say i visited the site on 9pm, it says that the person visited it like 3 hours earlier, is there a way to set the timezone?

Thanks!
(Sorry for my worse english)

Comment: `.htaccess` file.  Here is a great resource https://github.com/phanan/htaccess

Comment: for your timezone question `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

Comment: You couold put it outside of the web root

Comment: How do i set the timezone to germany ?

Comment: Im quiet new to php / html, so it's kinda hard for me to figure this out myself.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard beat me to it. Just be sure the location is writable by the web server process.

Comment: Alright i'll try that. Thanks for the help

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');` you just add this to the top of your php file you don't replace `date`

Comment: I can't get the time stuff to work & i cant find what im looking for on that site @cmorrissey.

Comment: Oh nice! Time is "working" now.

Comment: Nevermind! I have found it, thank you all for your help!